# is the junit jar part of JDK or JRE?

Tags: java, junit

I want to run junit on a deployed enviroment that only has JRE but not JDK.  I feel stupid asking this, but google has failed me.  Is the junit jar part of the JDK or the JRE?

Comment: The packages which come with the JDK start with `java.*` `javax.*` `sun.*` `sunw.*` or `com.sun.*` Almost all other packages are not part of the JDK.

Comment: Its really funny how everybody answered the exact same thing at the exact same minute :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither. JUnit is a third-party project. You can download it [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/downloads); version 4.11 was released yesterday.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not, [junit](http://www.junit.org/) is separate [framework](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit) itself and it is a opensource project.

Comment: +1, but you should be pointing people at github: https://github.com/KentBeck/junit

Comment: @MatthewFarwell The github repo link is dead

Answer (score 3):

No it is a third party jar you can get from junit.org